# Invalid use of 'this' in non-member function when calling function from unordered map in the int main() in C++

Tags: c++, function, dictionary

I have an unordered map assigning strings to function so I could execute them as if they were console commands, I can get the function but I'm unable to execute it no matter how I try. Most sources I have seen say I should use "`this`" but I still don't understand why won't it work

Here's my code:

main.h

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <unordered_map>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <algorithm>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    class Func_runner
    {
    public:
        unordered_map <string, void(Func_runner::*)()> commandHash = 
        {
            {"help", &Func_runner::help},
            {"clear", &Func_runner::clear},
            {"ver", &Func_runner::displayVersion},
            {"mkfile", &Func_runner::makeFile},
            {"view", &Func_runner::viewFile}
        };
    
        void help();
        void clear();
        void displayVersion();
        void makeFile();
        void viewFile();
    
        // commandHash["help"] = &Func_runner::help;
        // commandHash["clear"] = &Func_runner::clear;
        // commandHash["mkfile"] = &Func_runner::makeFile;
        // commandHash["ver"] = &Func_runner::displayVersion;
        // commandHash["view"] = &Func_runner::edit;
    };
    
    void Func_runner::help(){
        cout << "   help - Displays all available commands. \n   version - Displays Operating Version.\n   clear - Clears the screen.\n   makefile - Creates files.\n   view - Outputs text file contents to console.\n";
    }
    
    
    void Func_runner::clear(){
        system("CLS");
    }
    
    
    void Func_runner::displayVersion(){
        cout << "   Version 1.2R" << endl;
    }
    
    
    void Func_runner::makeFile(){
        string filename;
        string path;
        string text;
        cout << "   Filename: ";
        getline(cin, filename);
        cout << "   Path: ";
        getline(cin, path);
        ofstream File(path + filename);
        cout << "   Text (Optional): ";
        getline(cin, text);
        File << text;
        cout << "\n   File " << filename << " created." << endl;
        File.close(); 
    }
    
    
    void Func_runner::viewFile(){
        string editorfile;
        string myText;
        cout << "   Full path to file: ";
        getline(cin, editorfile);
        ifstream ReadFile(editorfile);
        while (getline (ReadFile, myText)) {
            cout << myText << endl;
        } 
    }
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include "func_obj.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){
    Func_runner runner; 
    
    bool running = true;

    // unordered_map<string, void(Func_runner::*)()> commandHash;

    // commandHash["help"] = &Func_runner::help;
    // commandHash["clear"] = &Func_runner::clear;
    // commandHash["mkfile"] = &Func_runner::makeFile;
    // commandHash["ver"] = &Func_runner::displayVersion;
    // commandHash["view"] = &Func_runner::edit;

    while(running){
        string command;
        cout << "Command: ";
        getline(cin, command);

        if(runner.commandHash.find(command) != runner.commandHash.end()) 
        {   
           (this->*runner.commandHash[command])();
            

            // int command_index = commandHash[command]; // old switch case useless with string -> func hash
            // switch (command_index){
            // case 1:
            //     runner.help();
            //     break;
            // case 2:
            //     runner.clear();
            //     break;
            // case 3:
            //     runner.displayVersion();
            //     break;
            // case 4:
            //     runner.makeFile();
            //     break;
            // case 5:
            //     runner.edit();
            //     break;
            // case 6:
            //     running = false;
            //     break;
            // }
        }

        else 
        {
            cout << "invalid command" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

There are a lot of random comments as that was an older version, I deactivated as I was afraid of losing it, don't mind them.

Comment: there is no `this` in `main`. `this` refers to the current object in member functions which `main` isnt. What object did you mean when you wrote `(this->*runner.commandHash[command])();` in `main` ?

Comment: This is invalid C++, `this` can only be used in the context of class member functions

Comment: btw please read about [mre]. A minimum code that has the same problem is `int main() { this->foo(); }`

Comment: I started learning c++ yesterday so i dont realy know much of the sintax the was my attempt at replicating this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936578/how-to-create-an-unordered-map-for-string-to-function

Comment: Use `(runner.*runner.commandHash[command])();` instead. There is no `this` in `main`. `this` is only defined within the context of a member function and `main` is not a member function. You need to provide an actual `Func_runner` instance, and luckily you already have one : `runner`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thx that worked fine, would you mind giving an explanation on why?(im very new jsut dont like running code i dont understand)

Comment: @cachaçeirosdohawaii Which part of the explanation that I already provided do you need clarification on?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux i got why 'this' was not working but i dont get what (runner*runner does

Comment: @cachaçeirosdohawaii Consider it this way instead : `void(Func_runner::*fptr)() = runner.commandHash[command];` followed by `(runner.*fptr)();`. The first part doesn't change, it it just getting the member function pointer. You already had this. The second part is broken down as such : `runner` is "which object to call the member function on", the `fptr` is a pointer to the member function to call, `*` dereferences that pointer and the trailing `()` call that function with no arguments. Does this help? Are you familiar with the difference between member functions and free functions?

Comment: @cachaçeirosdohawaii Another perspective : consider if `command` is `"help"` and compare `(runner.*fptr)();` with `runner.help()`. The `*fptr` part replaces `help`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Ok let me see if i got it, th e first `runner` specifies that we are using an instance of the Func_runner class `runner` being the object, the `runner.commandHash[command]`  passes witch of the Func_runner funtions we are using, the `*` separates them both and `()` jist says that it is argumentless?, also my familiarity with member and free functions is limited as i learnt it like 30min ago

Comment: @cachaçeirosdohawaii It seems to me that you understood correctly.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux ok thank very much

Comment: Part of what makes this confusing is that `commandHash` is a non-static data member despite containing no instance-specific information.  If you make it `static` you won’t have to have `runner` appear twice (although you’ll then need to also declare it `inline` or move its initializer to the `.cpp`).